# Notices: Undefined index and trying to get property of non-object include()

Tags: 7, theming

I have a "page--front.tpl.php" and get these notices:

> Notice: Undefined index: nodes include() (line 47 in file /home/dunmicro/public_html/sites/all/themes/dunartis/page--front.tpl.php).
>
> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object include()(line 47 in file /home/dunmicro/public_html/sites/all/themes/dunartis/page--front.tpl.php).

Here is my code:

```
<?php if ($site_name): ?>
    <?php if ($title): ?>
      <div id="site-name"<?php if ($disable_site_name) { print ' class="hidden"'; } ?>>
        <strong>
          <a href="<?php print $front_page; ?>" title="<?php print t('Home'); ?>" rel="home">
                      <span><?php print $page['content']['system_main']['nodes']['63']['#node']->title; ?></span></a>
        </strong>
      </div>
    <?php else: /* Use h1 when the content title is empty */ ?>
      <h1 id="site-name"<?php if ($disable_site_name) { print ' class="hidden"'; } ?>>
        <a href="<?php print $front_page; ?>" title="<?php print t('Home'); ?>" rel="home">
                    <span><?php print $page['content']['system_main']['nodes']['63']['#node']->title; ?></span></a>
      </h1>
    <?php endif; ?>
  <?php endif; ?>
```

How do I fix these notices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check if `$page['content']['system_main']['nodes']` is set or not:

Please check updated code:

```
<?php if ($site_name): ?>
    <?php if ($title): ?>
      <div id="site-name"<?php if ($disable_site_name) { print ' class="hidden"'; } ?>>
        <strong>
          <a href="<?php print $front_page; ?>" title="<?php print t('Home'); ?>" rel="home">
                      <span>
<?php if(isset($page['content']['system_main']['nodes'])):?>
<?php print $page['content']['system_main']['nodes']['63']['#node']->title; ?>
<?php endif;?>
</span></a>
        </strong>
      </div>
    <?php else: /* Use h1 when the content title is empty */ ?>
      <h1 id="site-name"<?php if ($disable_site_name) { print ' class="hidden"'; } ?>>
        <a href="<?php print $front_page; ?>" title="<?php print t('Home'); ?>" rel="home">
                    <span>
<?php if(isset($page['content']['system_main']['nodes'])):?>
<?php print $page['content']['system_main']['nodes']['63']['#node']->title; ?>
<?php endif;?>
</span></a>
      </h1>
    <?php endif; ?>
  <?php endif; ?>
```